# Oracle SQL: How to perform comparison by converting "Varchar" to "Number"

Tags: sql, oracle, type-conversion, number-formatting

I have only read-only access to Oracle SQL (Can use SELECT command only).

I want to perform the comparison conditions on a `Varchar` type column by converting it to `Number` type.

**Reference Data:**

```
   ID | Price | Currency
-------------------------
  548 | 6000  |   USD
 9784 | 7000  |   EUR
  254 | 5000  |   USD
```

**Query used:**

```
select id, price, currency
  from ( select item_id id,
                to_number(item_price) price,
                item_currency currency
           from item
          where item_price is not null) A 
 where A.price <= 6000;
```

**Expected Output:**

```
   ID | Price | Currency
------------------------- 
  548 | 6000  |   USD
  254 | 5000  |   USD
```

Comment: So what is wrong with the query you posted?  Why doesn't it work for you?

Comment: @APC, I am facing below issue while running the query:


    ORA-01722: invalid number
    01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
    *Cause:    
    *Action:

Comment: Can you provide us the reference data that has that invalid number 01722 (it's the leading zero that is the issue)?  Because I agree with APC -- your query should work and give back something like this.         ID      PRICE
---------- ----------
CURRENCY
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       548       6000
USD

       254       5000
USD

       123       1722
USD

Comment: What version of Oracle?  In 12.1, you could embed the `is_number` function from @APC's answer in a SQL statement rather than needing to be able to create a stored function in the database.  In prior versions, this gets hard if you can't define a function and no one has already defined a function to identify numeric values.

Comment: @JustinCave, My organisation is using Oracle 3.2.20.09.87, thats why I use that version.
Is there any way to convert the "String" type data in "Numeric" type ? In the "String" type data, we have the values like "5000.56", "8745.23" etc. Now, because of the "decimal" character, we are using "String" datatype.

Comment: That version number does not make sense.  That's not a version of the Oracle database.  What does querying 'v$version' show?

Comment: @JustinCave, I have checked the version.
It is "Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production".

Comment: There must be some strings in the database that are not valid numbers.  The string "5000.56" wouldn't cause an error, for example, unless your session expects that the comma rather than the period is the decimal separator.

Answer (score 1):

"ORA-01722: invalid number" means what it says: you are attempting to cast a string to a number when the string contains a non-numeric value.

This is the danger of using weakly-typed columns.  People  always say, "our application will validate the input" .  But the one thing you can guarantee is that someone (or something) will stick a non-numeric value into that column.

Okay, so hindsight is a marvellous thing and you probably don't want a lecture from me about data integrity: what, practically, can you do?  Basically you need to identify the values which won't cast to numbers and handle them somehow (change the value, filter them from the query, whatever).

There's no Oracle built in to test for numberness but it's easy to write one:

```
create or replace function is_number (p_str in varchar2)
    return varchar2
 is
     return_value varchar2(5);
     n number;
 begin
     begin
         dbms_output.put_line('str='||p_str);
         n := to_number(p_str);
         return_value := 'TRUE'; 
     exception
         when invalid_number or value_error then
             dbms_output.put_line('here');
             return_value := 'FALSE'; 
         when others then
             dbms_output.put_line(sqlerrm);
             raise; 
     end;
     return return_value; 
end;
/
```

Here's one way to use it.

```
with cte as ( select id, price, currency from item
              where is_number(price) = 'TRUE')
select id, price, currency
from cte
where to_number(price) <= 6000;
```

Comment: just to share more info:
'"ORA-01722: invalid number" means what it says: you are attempting to cast a string to a number when the string contains a non-numeric value.'

Yes, the column type is "Varchar", as the values in that column contains "decimal character" like "6000.00", "505.40" etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CAST() function.

Example of using it is below

```
SELECT product_id, CAST(ad_sourcetext AS VARCHAR2(30)) FROM print_media;
```

For more informations visit [THIS](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions016.htm).

Hope it helps

Comment: I am facing below issue while running the query:
 ORA-01722: invalid number
 01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
 *Cause:    
 *Action:

_I face the same error when I run my previous query._

Comment: If you have string which contains non number characters, first remove that kind of characters and then cast that string to integer. To get familiar with replacing that characters to empty spaces `""` using `REPLACE`  [check this](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/replace.php)